# What is the "right" way to return a new class object from a VBA function?

Tags: class, vba, object, creation

I am looking for the proper way to create and return a new class object in VBA.

I am familiar with the following pattern for returning a new *Type* variable (returned by value):

```
Public Type Foo
    x as Integer
    y as Integer
End Type

Public Function NewFoo() as Foo
    NewFoo.x = 4
    NewFoo.y = 2
End Function
```

What would be the equivalent syntax for a new *Class* object (returned by reference)?

```
Public Function NewMyClass() As MyClass
    ''// ...?
End Function
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to return an Object in VBA you have to set it to the Method name

```
Public Function NewMyClass() As MyClass
    Set NewMyClass = CreateObject("Some.MyClass");
End Function
```

Comment: Awesome. Can I then still use `NewMyclass.someVariable = someValue`?

Comment: As far as i know you can treat the NewMyclass as a normal variable, therefore you should also be able to call methods an properties